# What is the origin of the "Pickle" switch for release of ordnance?

Tags: military, aviation-history, terminology, cockpit, b17-flying-fortress

I am looking for proper proof of the theory that it is called so due to the Norden sight of the B17, which was said to assist the bomber in putting a bomb into a pickle jar, and hence it stuck.

Comment: Seems unlikely, as "Pickle" generally implies the emergency, unaimed, instantaneous release of all ordinance.

Comment: @quietflyer  No, I think the OP is right, although I don't have a source at hand. To "pickle" is simply to release; ideally with the precision that the bomb lands in the proverbial pickle barrel, but if necessary they land where-ever. (Hopefully, not armed, in the latter case.)

Comment: Pickle switch reference -- https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/us/boeing-inappropriately-coached-faa-test-pilots-during-review-of-737-max-after-deadly-crashes-senate-investigators-say/ar-BB1c3asu?li=BBnbcA1

Answer (score 5):

The accuracy of the Norden bombsight was often exaggerated, but it was never claimed it could put a bomb into a pickle jar. [The exaggerated claim from the Norden Company was that a bombardier using it under "ideal" conditions could put a bomb into a pickle barrel from 20,000 feet AGL.](https://masseyaero.org/news/Norden.html) In reality it could barely get within 100 ft of the target from 10,000 feet AGL. (AGL = Above Ground Level) Some sources claim that it's called a pickle switch because a control handle with many switches almost feels like a pickle with all its bumps, but that would imply the name was given considerably later than WW2.

Comment: I would agree with the later because "pickle" is used in contexts other than releasing bombs, although who's to say it didn't evolve from that...

Comment: I also heard another theory, which says that the pickle switch naming was due to earlier submarines that launched Torpedos- which looked like pickles, and it then moves to the aviation world.

Answer (score -2):

We made these in the 60s for USAF for release of PLADS AND LAPES SYSTEMS.  Comfortable grip and knobby for a good grip, hence pickle

Comment: Welcome to [Aviation.se]! Who is "we"? What are "PLADS AND LAPES SYSTEMS" and does it have to be ALL SHOUT CASE? Is this actually the origin of the term? Do you have any sort of reference that might support this claim?

Comment: [LAPES](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgg3iRaVnbw)